# How can I change the viewport shading to 'Texture Solid'?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

Can someone tell me where is texture solid button in 2.77?
I cannot find it anywhere.
I cannot see it in Shading menu.

Comment: What 3D viewport shading mode are you in? Textured, Solid, Wireframe, Rendered...?

Answer (score 1):

The shading panel's options are Mode dependent.

Means,Every shading mode has his own option,*Texture Solid* is one of the *Solid Mode* option so you have to be in *Solid Mode* to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

If you notice on the dock below the viewport screen it says what mode your in. I'm in object mode. Next to it there is a white circle. Clicking on it will show your options on how to display the objects. after clicking on a drop-down (or drop-up) menu will appear. [image: viewport shading] 

Click on Texture. Done!