# How can I see the texture in viewport

Tags: rendering, texturing

I read a bunch of tutorials but I can't get the texture to show up in the viewport and the render view.

This tutorial is telling me Im supposed to change the Display Method from Solid and change some Object interaction Mode to texture.

I dont see where this is, everything is backwards in this program. Can someone please show me on a screen shot what I need to change in order for the texture to show up on the model in the viewport and in the render?

https://all3dp.com/2/blender-how-to-add-a-texture/

Comment: What render engine? What Blender version in your case? Can you edit question with at least a screenshot of what is not working in your case?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87171/why-does-the-material-tab-has-a-different-layout Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles/8698#8698

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my material panel look different?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/why-does-my-material-panel-look-different)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the viewport shading to 'Texture Solid'?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53676/how-can-i-change-the-viewport-shading-to-texture-solid)